# Looking for researches or case studies on How to move users from engaging / visiting social media to website

Tags: research

Are there any resources, articles, research documents or case studies explains how companies or apps succeed to move users from social media to their website?

On other words: create motivation and building a transitional road map from social media to website

example: Instagram account sells goods, and want to move to e-commerce website but currently exploring opportunities how to do that (fear of the idea that its business is currently based on being a social-based store)

context: I’m currently on secondary research for UX project and I want to explore this specific area in order to get some assumptions to be validated.

Comment: What kind of research have you found so far? What search terms have you used? So that we don't duplicate your findings.

Comment: until now I didn't find any relevant searches for this inquires:
"Move users from social media"
"Exit users from social media"
"Pull Off users from social media"
"success Pull Off users from social media"

Comment: @EamgeMorata If this answer helped you you can set as right answer clicking on check icon aside of the answer and upvoted if is useful to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, these researches [Average Click-Through Rate on Facebook](https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2017/02/28/facebook-advertising-benchmarks) and [What is a “Good” Click-Through Rate?](https://conversionxl.com/guides/click-through-rate/benchmarks/) could help you.

[image]

You also could try to search by:

- social conversion rate
- social engagement statistics
- social media enquiries conversion rate
- social media ctr average

or any other similar words.